# Why does the warping of spacetime make objects move closer together?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature

I understand why the warping of spacetime affects moving objects, but why would it affect stationary ones if it even does? Would two completely stationary objects not move closer together because they aren't moving in space therefore wouldn't start bending space towards each other? And if they do, why would they move towards each other? If there's no movement, then there would be no movement to bend towards the other object.

Comment: It can also make them move apart. It depends on the type of warping.

Comment: there is no such thing as a stationary object versus a moving object in relativity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would two completely stationary objects not move closer together because they aren't moving in space therefore wouldn't start bending space towards each other?

No. Spacetime has four dimensions. All objects are moving forward in time. Spacetime curvature around a static massive object is primarily in the time direction. To put it colloquially, the time direction is curved radially inward, so that temporal velocity is rotated into a inward spatial velocity and this is what is observed as gravitational attraction.

In addition, objects do not "start bending" space toward each other. Mass and energy always curve spacetime. The movement of objects change according to curvature, which in turn changes according to their movement. It's a dynamical process.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Is there an answer to why it would move?

Comment: Rather than thinking of objects as moving forward in time, it is clearer (and more faithful to the physics) to simply understand them as being extended in a time direction. So, for example, a point in 3D space is a line in 4D spacetime. Those lines tend to follow spacetime curvature for the simple reason that they are "locally straight" (in the absence of nongravitational influence).

Comment: @HunterSherring By definition. Points in spacetime are events (i.e. a specific position and instant in time). And objects don't exist for just a single instant in time. You may know from special relativity that all objects move through spacetime with speed $c$ regardless of their spatial velocity. This remains true in GR.

Comment: Good answer, except: “*Spacetime curvature around a static massive object is primarily in the time direction.* - is technically incorrect. The zero Ricci tensor in vacuum ensures that the time dilation equals the length contraction. Perhaps what you meant to say was; “*in space-time the curvature of space has nothing to do with gravity (the 'curvature of time’, one could say)*” - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellis_wormhole

Answer (score 0):

Warping of space-time is only a figurative way to express some mathematical equations. Even the familiar Newtonian gravity can be viewed in this geometric fashion:
$$\mathbf F = \frac{-GMm\mathbf{\hat r}}{r^2}$$ If only gravity acts on the mass:
$$m\mathbf a = \frac{-GMm\mathbf{\hat r}}{r^2} \implies \frac{ d^2\mathbf r}{dt^2} = \frac{-GM\mathbf{\hat r}}{r^2}\implies \frac{ d^2\mathbf r}{dt^2} + \frac{GM\mathbf{\hat r}}{r^2} = 0$$
This last expression can be interpreted by differential geometry as a geodesic equation in a curved space-time.